# How could I rewrite $\dfrac{6 + 4 {i}} { -9 - 4 {i}}$ in a+bi form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Peace to all. When I solve the problem I get $\dfrac{70} { 97}$ - $\dfrac{12{i}} {97}$ and it's the wrong answer. How exactly do you go about solving this problem?

This is my work: I received that answer by multiplying both the numerator and denominator by the conjugate partner of "-9 - 4i" which is "-9 + 4i".

$\dfrac{-54 + 24 {i} - 36{i} +16i^2} { 81 - 36 {i} + 36 {i} - 16i^2}$

Combining like terms: $\dfrac{-54 + 24 {i} - 36{i} +16(-1)} { 81 - 36 {i} + 36 {i} - 16(-1)}$ = $\dfrac{-70 - 12i} { 81 + 16}$ = $\dfrac{-70} { 97}$ - $\dfrac{12{i}} {97}$

Comment: Please show all your work. How did you get that number?

Comment: You got a sign wrong somewhere.  I'm getting that the numerator should be $-70-12i$.   Your edited question has the correct answer, which is different from your original answer.  $(-9-4i)(-9+4i)=81+16=97$, not $-97$.

Comment: @RobertShore As I was writing it I noticed that I didn't copy the correct sign from my work. It's those tiny minute (important) details that I overlook sometimes with math. Thank you

Comment: "$\dfrac{70 -  12 {i}} {97}$ or $\dfrac{70{i}} { 97}$ - $\dfrac{12{i}} {97}$". Why did you write "or" in between these expressions? These both expressions are different. $\dfrac{70 -  12 {i}} {97} = \dfrac{70}{97} - \dfrac{12i}{97}$. You wrongly splitted the expression. Additionally I think your intention was to write $\dfrac{-70 -12i}{97} $ not $\dfrac{70-12i}{97}$. Please edit it.

Comment: @ProThala Thank you, changes made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid confusion, we better take out the negative sign of the denominator first and then multiply the conjugate of 9+4i.

$\displaystyle {\quad \frac{6+4i}{-9-4i}\\= -\frac{6+4i}{9+4i}\cdot\frac{9-4i}{9-4i} \\=-\frac{70+12i}{81+16} \\=-\frac{70}{97} -\frac{12}{97} i}$

$$\textrm{ :|D Wish it helps!} $$

Comment: (+1) nice explanation :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your appreciation!

Answer (score 1):

By multiplying both the numerator and denominator by the conjugate partner of "-9 - 4i" which is "-9 + 4i", you will get:

$\dfrac{-54 + 24 {i} - 36{i} +16i^2} { 81 - 36 {i} + 36 {i} - 16i^2}$

Then combining like terms:

$\dfrac{-54 + 24 {i} - 36{i} +16(-1)} { 81 - 36 {i} + 36 {i} - 16(-1)}$ = $\dfrac{-70 - 12i} { 81 + 16}$ =  $\dfrac{-70} { 97}$ - $\dfrac{12{i}} {97}$

Hope this assists anyone who has/had similar difficulties in solving an equation similar to or like the one above.

Comment: @Moo Thank you, changes made

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that can be taken is through the application of the definition of division.  If $ \ \frac{6 + 4 i}{ -9 - 4 i} \ = \ a + bi \ \ , $ then
$$ 6 \ + \ 4i \ \ = \ \ (-9 \ - \ 4i)·(a \ + \ bi) \ \ = \ \ -9a \ - \ 4ai \ - \ 9bi \ - \ 4b·i^2 \ \ . $$
Equating the real and imaginary parts produces the pair of equations $ \ -9a + 4b \ = \ 6 \ \ , \ \ -4a - 9b \ = \ 4 \ \ . $  Solving this system by multiplication and addition
[first array: multiply first equation by 9 , second by 4 ; second array: multiply first equation by (-4) , second by 9] yields

$$ \begin{array}{ccc} -81a & + \ 36b & \ = \ 54 \\ -16a &   - \ 36b & \ = \ 16 \end{array} \ \ \ , \ \ \  \begin{array}{ccc} 36a & - \ 16b & \ = \ -24 \\ -36a & \ - \ 81b & \ = \ 36 \end{array} $$
[then add equations together]

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ -97a \ \ = \ \ 70 \ \ \ , \ \ \ -97b \ \ = \ \ 12 \ \ . $$

Hence, the ratio is $ \ \large{\frac{6  \ + \  4 i}{ -9 \ - \ 4 i}} \ = \ \normalsize{-\frac{70}{97}   - \frac{12}{97}i} \ \ , $
in agreement with the result from other posters.

$$ \ \ $$

The multiplication of the numerator and denominator of a ratio of complex numbers by the complex conjugate in order to "rationalize" the denominator is, of course, the conventional method of simplification.  It can be "reduced" to a formula (although the calculations are usually simple enough that the formula isn't generally taught):
$$ \frac{a \ + \ bi}{c \ + \ di} \ · \ \frac{c \ - \ di}{c \ - \ di}  \ \ = \ \ \frac{ac \ + \ bd}{c^2 \ + \ d^2} \ + \ i·\left(\frac{bc \ - \ ad}{c^2 \ + \ d^2} \right) \ \ ;  $$
for this problem, we then obtain
$$ \frac{6·(-9) \ + \ 4·(-4)}{(-9)^2 \ + \ (-4)^2} \ + \ i·\left(\frac{4·(-9) \ - \ 6·(-4)}{(-9)^2 \ + \ (-4)^2} \right) $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{(-54) \ + \ (-16)}{81 \ + \ 16} \ + \ i·\left(\frac{(-36) \ - \ (-24)}{81 \ + \ 16} \right) \ \ . $$
Because the method of solving a system of two linear equations is equivalent, there is a way of representing complex numbers as $ \ 2 \times 2 \ $ matrices, $ \ a + bi \ \rightarrow \ \left[\begin{array}{cc}  a &  b  \\ -b &   a  \end{array} \right] \ \ . $  [I mention this approach since many "algebra/pre-calculus" course at least introduce matrices.]  Multiplying two complex numbers then gives the same result as multiplying two such matrices and division involves multiplying the matrix representing the numerator by the *inverse* of the matrix representing the denominator.  For this problem,
$$ 6 + 4i \ \rightarrow \ \left[\begin{array}{cc}  6 &  4  \\ -4 &   6  \end{array} \right] \ \ , \ \ -9 - 4i \ \rightarrow \ \left[\begin{array}{cc}  -9 &  -4  \\ 4 &   -9  \end{array} \right] $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{1}{-9 - 4i} \ \ = \ \ \left[\begin{array}{cc}  -9 &  -4  \\ 4 &   -9  \end{array} \right]^{-1} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{(-9)·(-9) \ - \ 4·(-4)} \left[\begin{array}{cc}  -9 &  4  \\ -4 &   -9  \end{array} \right] \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{97} \left[\begin{array}{cc}  -9 &  4  \\ -4 &   -9  \end{array} \right] \ \ ; $$

$$ \frac{6  \ + \  4 i}{ -9 \ - \ 4 i} \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \frac{1}{97} \left[\begin{array}{cc}  -9 &  4  \\ -4 &   -9  \end{array} \right] \ \left[\begin{array}{cc}  6 &  4  \\ -4 &   6  \end{array} \right] \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{97} \left[\begin{array}{cc}  -54 - 16 &  -36+24  \\ -24 + 36 &   -16-54  \end{array} \right]  $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{1}{97} \left[\begin{array}{cc}  -70 &  -12  \\ 12 &   -70  \end{array} \right] \ \ , $$
which represents the complex number $ \ -\frac{70}{97}   - \frac{12}{97}i \ \ . $